# Is the PHP memory limit shared between different people accessing a website?

Tags: php

I did some searching about this but got a lot of shared hosting type responses. I am using Amazon EC2 which is different.

My question is, if I give PHP a memory limit of 512MB, is that limit per person/session accessing the website? Or for PHP in total?

So for example, if two people accessed the website at the same time.

- User 1 uses 10MB
- User 2 uses 12MB

Is that 22MB out of 512MB used?

Or does each person have 512MB of memory so User 1 has 502MB left and User 2 has 500MB left?

Comment: That limit is per process.

Comment: No. It is per-process. So 10/512 and 12/512 respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your latter conjecture is correct -- The memory limit is for each PHP process. Any process may have to allocate a certain minimum/maximum amount of RAM. Take Java for example, where initial RAM allocation is explicitly done in `-Xms128M -Xmx512M`.

For PHP, RAM is initially allocates a minimal amount of memory (8 MB?), but it can grow to the limit specified in php.ini or memory_limit(). Once *the process* hits that limit, your script crashes with `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of x bytes exhausted`.

PHP is incapable of self-regulating its global RAM usage. If you really want to do this, one option is to check the total system free RAM at the start of your PHP script like described here, and if it surpasses a threshold, send a system overloaded message.